# Animator options - How to render hundreds of animations efficiently

Tags: unity

So, I've spent the last few weeks reading up on animations and what alternatives I have to the Animator component since it's performance is awful. So far I have not found an alternative that would fit my scenario.

I am making an RTS and will have hundreds of units animating on screen. Using Animator and skinned meshes is not an option due to the horrible performance. So my option are:

1. Use legacy Animation system. While this might improve performance, it's not enough. Also using a legacy anything just feels weird.
2. Use a crowd-animation asset or make my own compute shader that creates textures for each animation and then can be used as a simple mesh, allowing batching. This is great for performance, a bit scrit-heavy but thats fine. My issue with this option is that it will not use IKs since it takes in the animation data without any post-processing like IKs, and if you use animations from Mixamo or assets, youll have issues like feet-shuffle that can only be solved with foot-IKs.
3. Using ReadPixels (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.ReadPixels.html) to render the animations into image files like .png and then use them as sprites. This is an option that would let me take advantage of foot-IKs. However I cannot find any information on how to begin an approach here, and **this is where I could use some help**. Is there any resource out there that does this or shows how it is done?
4. Use another tool like Blender, Maya or Houdini first. Workflow could be: find anim to use > import to Maya > Add foot IKs to remove feet shuffle > Bake animation > import to unity where it now works without IKs. **Is this possible?** Im not familiar with these other tools.

Other than that, just **any solution that will let me play hundreds of animations without losing foot-IKs** is what I need, so any information surrounding that is appriciated. Any form of animation baking that happens in playmode is what I am after.

Comment: I think you might want to consider scaling levels of detail here. When you're zoomed in close enough to a few units to be able to notice foot sliding, transition those units to a more full-featured animation system that handles the IK. When you're zoomed out far enough to see hundreds of units (and probably can't see that many pixels of detail around each one's feet), transition them to a lower-fidelity animation system that prioritizes speed/throughput.

Comment: The unity DOTS packages sound like they might be useful for a game like this, although I’ve heard the animation portion is still pretty barebones. And the Dots package as a whole is not very polished yet.

Comment: @AdamB DOTS is not really an option for me, I do not have time to learn DOTS and re-write my game code Im afraid :(

Comment: If your performance issue is with the skinned mesh, I remember finding [this Unity experimental skinned mesh batcher](https://blog.unity.com/technology/animation-instancing-instancing-for-skinnedmeshrenderer), though of course it was never finished :( According to [this blog](https://blog.unity.com/technology/srp-batcher-speed-up-your-rendering), SRP doesn't seem to support skinned mesh batching either.